# Rename files to number and increasing if they already uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, rename, uploadify

Im using Uploadify to upload multiple images...

With this php code im proccess upload and store to server...

All this working fine...
But i need to rename images while upload , rename to number and start from 1
example

**1.jpg**
**2.jpg**
**3.jpg**
**4.jpg**
**etc...**

```
// The upload directory
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'.$_POST['folder'].'/';

if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $dir)) {
    mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $dir);
}
// Allowed file extensions
$fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'); 

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];  
    $targetFiles = $dir . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the filetype
    $fileParts = pathinfo($targetFiles);
    if (in_array(strtolower($fileParts['extension']), $fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFiles);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        // The file type wasn't allowed
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this is working. It isn't looping through the files so it will only work on  the first file. I'll attempt to rewrite it with a loop but see if you can spot the problem. You can easily rename a file as the second parameter of move_uploaded_files($originalFile, $targetFile);

Comment: Uploadify call this php file for every image when you try to upload, so if you upload multiple files like 10 images, this php above will run 10 times for every single images...

So php should be check in $dir folder if images with number x is already there if not rename it...

Have no idea hot to make it

Comment: Your question didn't make any of that clear which makes people waste time. Please be clear in your question what is supposed to happen.